# Intermediate Value Theorem where the Max=Min

Tags: calculus

The question I have received is that given $p(x)=x^3-4x$, show that $p(x)<0$ for all $x ∈ (0,2)$. It is supposed to be shown using the intermediate value theorem(I.V.T) and the suggestion is to do it by contradiction.

My contradiction hypothesis was $p(x)≥0$ for all $x ∈ [0,2]$, but how does the I.V.T operate when
$p(a)=p(b)$? I'm not confident on this so any suggestion of how to tackle this.

Comment: I mean, why would you need the IVT for this? Just observe that $x^3-4x = x(x^2-4)$. If $0 < x < 2$, then $0 < x^2 < 4$. This implies that $p(x) < 0$.

Comment: I know that I don't need to but I'm trying to see if it can be used

Comment: The contradiction to $p(x)<0$ for all $0<x<2$ is: $p(x)\ge 0$ for some $0<x<2.$